# In Skyrim, why aren't all pickpocketed items marked as stolen?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've noticed that some items that I've pickpocketed are not marked as stolen and I can freely sell them to any merchant that buys that item type.

It's not all items of a specific type. For example, some stolen necklaces are not marked as stolen and some are.

Some examples are [Calcemo's Ring](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Delivery_to_Calcelmo), shields, imperial bows, and lots of random jewelry. Basically, anyone unfortunate enough to walk past me gets their pocket picked.

Is this a bug? Could it be a side effect of a mod? Or is it some game mechanic that I don't quite understand yet?

I play on PC with Hearthfire and Dragonborn DLCs.

Note that I've never given any of these items to a follower or put them in a container of any kind. I've also never used the fence items option of the Amazing Follower Tweaks mod.

Thank you.

### Update

I've tried starting a fresh game with no mods installed and it still happens. So, it doesn't look like this is caused by a mod. I guess it'll just be a mystery. It's a beneficial effect, anyway.

Comment: I think this would be better received if it were about the base game (perhaps including the DLC). Would an answer that ignores all those mods be useful to you?

Comment: From looking at your list, Sneak Tools seems a likely culprit, but there's no telling. I would follow @tjd 's advice.

Comment: Asking us to diagnose an issue in among numerous mods is sort of unreasonable. I've voted to close as too broad due to that.

Comment: @Frank I wan't asking for a diagnosis of the issue exactly. I was hoping for someone else who has already experienced issues with the stolen flag and know the cause. I included my list of mods for people who already have one or more of them installed and are familiar with any issues with them.

Comment: If it still happens in the base game, I wonder if those people are your "friends". There's a mechanic in Skyrim where, once you do something for someone, they become your friend, and you can take most things from their house without it being stealing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a [mechanic in Skyrim called disposition](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Disposition). There is a table on that UESP page listing the different types of relationships the player can have with NPCs, and the level of disposition necessary to achieve it:

```
Value   Console name    Item value
-4      Archnemesis     
-3      Enemy   
-2      Foe     
-1      Rival   
 0      Acquaintance    
 1      Friend          25
 2      Confidant       50
 3      Ally            100
 4      Lover           500
```

The page states that

> The default relationship rank is 0 (Acquaintance) and it can vary between -4 and 4. The gold amount is the maximum value of an item you may take from someone at a certain rank without it being considered theft.

I know for certain that this applies to items they own in their house. For instance, if you follow Hadvor to Riverwood, then shortly after speaking with Alvor you can loot most of the stuff from his house.

I assume it applies to pickpocketing as well. Therefore, these items that aren't marked as stolen were probably stolen from a Friend or better, and were under the allowed value.

Comment: This does kind of make sense. I try to improve my disposition with everyone I can... Only to potentially kill them later when trying to max out the Ebony Blade :) That may be it. This is the best explanation so far. I'll wait a few days before accepting your answer in case someone else knows something that might affect it.